# can't pair mac and arduino fio with bluetooth bee

Tags: macos, bluetooth, arduino

I can't get my arduino fio with bluetooth bee paired with my mac.  I got my application working with a different board (arduino uno) and USB connection.  The code I'm uploading to my arduino fio is below:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial softSerial(2, 3); // RX, TX


void setup() {

    // bluetooth bee setup
    softSerial.print("\r\n+STWMOD=0\r\n");     // set to slave
    delay(1000);
    softSerial.print("\r\n+STNA=MYAPP\r\n");     // set name
    delay(1000);
    //  Serial.print("\r\n+STAUTO=1\r\n");     // permit auto-connect of paired devices
    softSerial.print("\r\n+STOAUT=1\r\n");
    delay(1000);
    //Serial.print("\r\n +STPIN=0000\r\n");  // set PIN
    //delay(1000);
    softSerial.print("\r\n+STBD=9600\r\n");     // set baud
    delay(2000);  // required 
    // initiate BTBee connection
    softSerial.print("\r\n+INQ=1\r\n");
    delay(20000);   // wait for pairing
    // Start the software serial.
    softSerial.begin(9600);
    // Start the hardware serial. 
    Serial.begin(9600);
}
```

I think the pins are right -- [2 and 3 seem to be the pins that connect to the bluetooth bee](http://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Dev/Arduino/Boards/Arduino-Fio-v23.pdf).  I've been googling for 2 days straight, and people don't seem to have problems pairing.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: What's the problem? Do you see the USB device? Have you tried the examples from here: http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/Bluetooth_Bee

Comment: Yeah -- if you'll see, the only substantial difference between my logic and theirs on setup is the PIN numbers, which *seem* to me to be right for the Fio (I could be wrong.)  After uploading the sketch, I reattach the bluetooth bee, turn on the board, and try to set up a new bt device on the mac (where it isn't ever seen.)

Comment: I think if the INQ mode is successful, I should be getting two LEDs of different colors flashing on the BluetoothBee.  As it is I only get one green one flashing.  Could point to the wrong pins being specified in the code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok -- this took me nearly three solid days of Google-fu, and I stumbled across [this page](http://esoftserve.com/?p=64).  Apparently that guy, also, had an immense amount of trouble finding a solution, so hopefully having the solution posted on StackOverflow will help future inquirers.

Really, two things are necessary.  First, for whatever reason, I have no idea why, you don't worry about the "software serial".  Just address the "Serial". Secondly, it will not work if you don't have the baud for the Serial at 38400.  I'm actually using a "software serial" to talk to another device, and that baud is at 9600, but for the bluetooth Serial, you want it at 38400.

If you define "setup" as follows, the BluetoothBee should blink red and green, and pair (mac has nothing to do with it):

```
long DATARATE = 38400;  // default data rate for BT Bee

char inChar = 0;
int  LED = 13;   // Pin 13 is connected to a LED on many Arduinos

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(DATARATE);

  // bluetooth bee setup
  Serial.print("\r\n+STWMOD=0\r\n");     // set to slave
  delay(1000);
  Serial.print("\r\n+STNA=myDeviceName\r\n");     // set the device name
  delay(1000);
  Serial.print("\r\n+STAUTO=0\r\n");     // don't permit auto-connect
  delay(1000);
  Serial.print("\r\n+STOAUT=1\r\n");     // existing default
  delay(1000);
  Serial.print("\r\n +STPIN=0000\r\n");  // existing default
  delay(2000);  // required

  // initiate BTBee connection
  Serial.print("\r\n+INQ=1\r\n");
  delay(2000);   // wait for pairing

  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
}
```

Then, after pairing you should see another serial port under 'tools -> serial port' in your Arduino IDE.  If you select that and define the "loop" function as follows, you should be able to send those commands and get verification that you are, in fact, talking to the bluetooth bee:

```
void loop() {

  // test app:
  //   wait for character,
  //   a returns message, h=led on, l=led off
  if (Serial.available()) {
    inChar = Serial.read();

    if (inChar == 'a') {
      Serial.print("connected");  // test return connection
    }

    if (inChar == 'h') {
      digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);   // on
    }

    if (inChar == 'l') {
      digitalWrite(LED, LOW);    // off
    }

  }

}
```